# Heroku - how to customize the runtime.txt and the requirementx.txt location

Tags: python, heroku

I have a project that I am running locally with docker-compose. I have the following structure:

```
/root
---> /backend
---> /frontend
---> /ia_worker
docker-compose.yaml
```

I want to host multiple apps on heroku. The problem is it appears this set-up isn't very compatible with heroku:

Heroku forces me to specify a `requirements.txt` and `runtime.txt` in the root folder to use the `heroku/python` buildpack.

I managed to move the backend Procfile to the `/backend` directory using this buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku-community/multi-procfile.tgz but all it does is just copying the backend/Procfile to Procfile when building the python app.

So this approach doesn't help to achieve my goal which is keeping `runtime.txt` and `requirements.txt` inside the `backend` folder.

Is there a way to specify a `WORKDIR` for `heroku/python` build ?